# Is it possible to join the new style inner join with an outer join?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Is it possible to combine the new inner join style with an outer join?

For example, something like:

```
select * from
table1, table2
where table1.columnA = table2.columnB
left outer join table3
on table3.columnA = table1.columnA
```

Comment: Just because something is possible does not mean it should be done. Ever.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but you have to put the `WHERE` clause after all your `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses:

```
select * 
from table1, table2
left outer join table3 on table3.columnA = table1.columnA
where table1.columnA = table2.columnB
```

But it's ugly and confusing so I wouldn't exactly *recommend* it. Stick with one style.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using INNER and (LEFT) OUTER JOIN, they must come before the WHERE clause.